# Convergence in product domain and null sets

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\int_0^\infty \int_\Omega |f_n(t,x) -f(t,x)|^2 \to 0$. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain.

Consider the following statements (I have relabelled subsequences so don't worry about that).

1. For a.a. $t$, $f_n(t,x) \to f(t,x)$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega$
2. For a.a. $x$, $f_n(t,x) \to f(t,x)$ for a.e. $t \in (0,\infty)$
3. For a.e. $(t,x) \in (0,\infty)\times \Omega$, $f_n(t,x) \to f(t,x)$.

Are they all true? My doubt is with the null sets treatment... I think they are true due to Fubini's theorem. Could someone explain it? Thank you.

Comment: Is part of your requirements that $f_n$ is measurable w.r.t. the product sigma algebra? Also, with "I have relabelled subsequences" you mean that you want to show "there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ such that ...?

Comment: @PhoemueX I would want $f_n$ and $f$ to be in Bochner spaces, so I think measurability in that sense. And yes that is what I mean.